# my shell variable in if statement which is inside of while loop

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I have below while loop which reads a file line by line for error codes, if this error code found in log.txt file, then I need to set alert=1 and then those errors are to be written a shell variable by concatenating them with a semicolon. But When I write below while loop it is not giving desired results.

log.txt file data:
ORA-03113
ORA-00933

errors.lst file data:
ORA-03113
ORA-00933
ERROR

```
export LOGFILE=/temp/log.txt
alert=0
error=""
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
if grep -q $line "$LOGFILE"; then
alert=1
error="${error};${line}"
fi
done < errors.lst
echo $alert
echo $error
```

I was expecting below output:
;ORA-03113;ORA-00933

But I am getting below output:
;ORA-00933

Can you please help me here, where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It works for me, do `dos2unix log.txt errors.lst`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your files contain `\r` (carriage return, ASCII
0xd). When your terminal emulator sees it, it removes everything it
has shown so far and moves to the beginning of the line. These
carriage return characters most commonly come from Windows-style line
endings. Run `dos2unix` on input files to get rid of them:

```
dos2unix log.txt errors.lst
```